# Cannot get filename from iframe I post to

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to upload an image using jQuery and PHP. I know there are many plugin solutions, but I'm using this. I can upload the file to the server with no problems, but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to get the file name so I can show the image. Is there any way to get the file name from the iframe I post to? Here is the code I am working with:

**jquery**

```
$('#file').change(function()
{ 
    var iframe = $('<iframe name="postiframe" id="postiframe" style="display:none" />');
    $("body").append(iframe);
    var form = $('#form');
    form.attr("action", "../hub.php?handler=add_item");
    form.attr("method", "post");
    form.attr("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
    form.attr("encoding", "multipart/form-data");
    form.attr("target", "postiframe");
    form.attr("file", $('#file').val());
    form.submit();
    $("#postiframe").load(function()
    {
        iframeContents=$("#postiframe")[0].contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
        console.log('added : '+iframeContents);                     
    });    
});
```

The above code outputs nothing other than the "added :" portion. Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: If the upload part works fine, you should be able to echo the filename in the PHP and it'll be displayed in your `iframeContents`.

Comment: You can use the [`contents`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) method, `$("#postiframe").contents()`

Comment: @ Fabrício Matté _ I did try that, but the PHP class I am using to resize the images return a boolean value. I really didn't really want to change code in the class if I could get the file name via client.

Comment: `.contents().find('body').html()` adds the overhead of 3 functions for something that already works cross-browser without those functions. @Mike I see, `$('#file').val()` can return the filename of the localhost, but chances are the file will be renamed in the server so there's no way to get it without a script or interaction to grab the filename from the server.

Comment: @ Raminson -  I tried what you suggested and in the log all I see is `<html>><head></head><body></body></html>`

Comment: @ Fabrício Matté - After you mention it I can see what your saying. I guess I will be writing some JSON :)

Comment: @ Fabrício Matté - I did what you said and simply added `print($file);` and that resolved my issue. How do I give you credit for the answer? Oh, and thank you for the help :)

Comment: Oh I must have missed a notification, wrote up a quick answer to don't leave this unanswered. `=]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `echo`/`print` the `filename` or `path` from the server after the upload is complete (preferably in `text/HTML` as you're posting to an `iframe`) so you can obtain it with Javascript as in your question's code.

```
iframeContents=$("#postiframe")[0].contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
console.log('added : '+iframeContents);
```

You may as well code a new JS request to fetch the uploaded images through Ajax to a new PHP (`echo`ing JSON for example), but it's unneeded if you want to get just the uploaded file in that form submit.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass some string data from iframe to main window using **window.name** technique.
Short example of using:

Iframe:

```
//doing your stuff, when finished store what you need in window.name property
window.name = '{"key1":"mydata1","key2":"mydata2"}'
window.location.href='about:blank';
```

Main window:

```
$(iframe).bind('load',function(){
    //triggered every time iframe's location is changed
    var iframe_data = this.contentWindow.name;
    if(!iframe_data.length) {
      //it's a first time iframe loaded
      return;
     }
    else{
      //iframe location is changed, we're expecting to receive some data
      $(this).unbind('load');
      console.log($.parseJSON(iframe_data));
      //{"key1":"mydata1","key2":"mydata2"}
    }

})
```

It should work even if the iframe placed at another origin (domain).
I didn't tested this code specifically, but it should work, i copypasted it from one of my projects

Comment: @ Valentin Kantor - I like what you have here, I will play with this code and see what I come up with. This would be a great alternative to a server response. Thank you!